# Chars not increasing array counter in while loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Vowels
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
  String vowels = "aeiou";
  int[] counters = new int[vowels.length()];

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Input file: ");
  String inputFileName = console.next();

  console.useDelimiter(""); 
  while (console.hasNext())
  {   

      char ch = console.next().charAt(0);
      ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if(ch == 'a')
        {
           counters[0]++;
        }
        if(ch == 'e')
        {
           counters[1]++;
        }
        if(ch == 'i')
        {
           counters[2]++;
        }
        if(ch == 'o')
        {
           counters[3]++;
        }
        if(ch == 'u')
        {
           counters[4]++;
        }
  }




  for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); i++)
  {
     System.out.println(vowels.charAt(i) + ": " + counters[i]);
  }

  }
 }
```

When i run the files it detects 3 e's only when it should be detecting several hundred of both. I don't see any issues with my code that would cause an issues please help. Im assuming it has to be between my delimiter and end of the while because the rest is out of the book.

Comment: Have you tried putting `System.out.println(ch);` in the while loop to see if it is doing the right thing? That might help to figure it out.

Comment: More importantly, have you tried `String term  = console.next(); System.out.println(term); ch = term.charAt(0);` to determine if your `useDelimiter("");` is actually giving you 1 character at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiter isn't working the way you think it is. Assuming you meant to read from the `inputFileName`, you could construct a `File` and `Scanner` to do so (remembering to close the `Scanner` in a `finally` block, or with a [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)). You can also determine the correct `counters` index by the position of the *vowel* in `vowels`. Finally, you might use formatted io for the output loop. Something like,

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
int[] counters = new int[vowels.length()];

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input file: ");
String inputFileName = console.nextLine().trim();
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName))) {
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        for (char ch : scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            int p = vowels.indexOf(ch);
            if (p >= 0) {
                counters[p]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%c: %d%n", vowels.charAt(i), counters[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code,

1. When you used `console.next();` the input has been assigned to `inputFileName`. That leaves the `console` with just the carriage return(`\r\n`).
2. Since you gave `new Scanner(System.in)`, your program will wait for the user to enter more input and will never end. `console.hasNext()` will never be false.

What you can do about it is, in the `while` loop get each character from `inputFileName` and then increment the vowel count.

If you wanted to get the input from a file, you should do

```
File file = new File(<path to file>);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Then your while loop will work. And remember to close `console` after reading the file.